# Output into string

Tags: c++, string, console, output

Hi I would like to transfer some couts into a string, how can I do that?
For instance:

```
std::cout << "The number of coronavirus infected: "<< allCount << std::endl;
std::cout << "The number of not infected: " << allpatient_ - allCount << std::endl;
std::cout << "The number of coronavirus infected hospitals: " << hospital << std::endl;
std::cout << "The number of not infected hospitals: " << hospitalcount_-hospital << std::endl;
std::cout << "The number of infected rooms in hospitals: " << room << std::endl;
std::cout << "The number of not infected rooms: " << hospitalcount_*roomcount_ - room << std::endl;
```

I would like to transform into a string, any tips?

Comment: Use `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: With this method how can I add variable into ostring?